# Why does this cPanel backup script stop working after no changes?

Tags: php, cpanel

I've been using the same backup cPanel backup script for a year and a half without fail and suddenly it stopped working without generating errors:

```
///From v-nessa.net
$auth = base64_encode("{$cpuser}:{$cppass}");
$domain = "https://my_domain.com:2083";
$theme = "paper_lantern";
$ftp = false;
$ftp_server = "";
$ftp_username = "";
$ftp_password = "";
$ftp_port = "21";
$ftp_directory = "/";

// Do not change below
$url = $domain . "/frontend/" . $theme . "/backup/dofullbackup.html";
$data = array();
if ($ftp) {
  $data["dest"] = "ftp";
  $data["server"] = $ftp_server;
  $data["user"] = $ftp_username;
  $data["pass"] = $ftp_password;
  $data["port"] = $ftp_port;
  $data["rdir"] = $ftp_directory;
}

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Basic $auth\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
  ),
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if (!$result) {
  exit("Error backing up server.");
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm aware that this particular script will fail if the theme is not correct, but from my cPanel I can see that it's still "paper_lantern".

Are there other ways that I might be able to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the cPanel "UAPI" instead. Here's how you can do a local homedir backup:

```
$cpuser = "username";
$cppass = "password";
$auth = base64_encode("{$cpuser}:{$cppass}");
$domain = "https://example.com:2083";
$notifyEmail = "user@example.com";

$url = $domain . "/execute/Backup/fullbackup_to_homedir?email=$notifyEmail";

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Basic $auth\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST'
  ),
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print($result);
```

You can adapt this for FTP or SCP - have a look at the other functions at https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Modules+-+Backup .